# Drupal 7 Dynamic Themes with paremeterized region settings

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, themes, drupal-themes

Are there any dynamic themes out there where there where all the parameters in each of the regions (size, color, position, font, justification, etc.) are variable settings where the site administrator user can modify these via the theme settings interface (e.g., select region and then be able to change and update the parameter values for the region)?

Ideally this would require absolutely no knowledge of CSS or any other technology on the part of the user.

I have developed a  program generators in the past and do not see why such functionality would be difficult to develop.  Is there any reason why such a functionality would not be desirable?  I am a developer but not very experienced with Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

[Omega](https://drupal.org/project/omega) (the version 3) may be what you need:

> Omega 3 is best suited to those who like to build their themes through
>   the user interface. The theme’s layout can be modified through the
>   theme settings and then contextually changed (different
>   layouts/settings for various portions of a site) through integration
>   with Delta and the Context module.

[Adaptative theme](https://drupal.org/project/adaptivetheme) is very configurable as well.